# MariaDB: Error Number 126 On Table Only When Updating specific field

Tags: mariadb

I have this problem on a database which seems to occur only when we try to update a specific field in a specific table.

This will trigger the error:

```
UPDATE post SET
     title = 'New Title here',
     iconid = 14
WHERE postid = 19486114;

MySQL Error   : Incorrect key file for table './johnforum/post.MYI'; try
to repair it
Error Number  : 126
```

While this will go through just fine:

```
UPDATE post SET
     iconid = 14
WHERE postid = 19486114;
```

In other words, only when we update the title field (a varchar) we get this error. We are running Server version: 5.5.66-MariaDB MariaDB Server running on 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

There is an enormous amount of disk space available, around 500GB. The table itself is around 20GB.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to repair the table as suggested? Also, while you have a lot of disk space, is there enough space on the partition for your `tmpdir`? Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';` to find your `tmpdir`.

Comment: Hello, I did one repair and the error keeps occurring. Trying to run myisamchk once more right now.

The tmp directory has huge amount of space available, so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Show `SHOW CREATE TABLE post` output.

Comment: And please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'post'`

Comment: Thanks guys, in the end I just backed up and recreated the table, and it fixed the issue. I am running some tests on the SSD as I suspect damage to the drive.